# Simple (SQLite-)database framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, frameworks

Do you know if there is a simple database framework that is free to use in iPhone development?

I've tried to get my head around Apple's framework SQLite3-framework, but it is just too complicated. Why can't it just be like PHP and databases …

So basically, what I want is a framework that is simple to use and can handle databases.

Thank you.

Comment: Does Core Data not fit your needs?

Comment: I don't know how to use Core Data. Do you have a tutorial?

Comment: The Apple docs are always the best place to start, but it might take a bit more effort to really get into it. Plus, they are always current, which other tutorials are not. Link: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @Emil, try doing a web search for "core data tutorial"....

Comment: Made this suggestion into an answer so it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Core data is not a relational database!! Remember that first and foremost. It has it's uses and should not be a substitute for sqlite. Use it when you need a persistent store. Refer to this article from apple describing what Core Data is and is not. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1

Apple's Sqlite3 database frameworks are actually pretty good. They function a lot like any sql you would be using.

Comment: The funny thing is that using SQLite directly is actually considerably harder to get right and make perform well than using Core Data.  "Why can't it just be like PHP and databases?" is often a question that is oft asked a few weeks before by "Why does my iPhone application perform horribly and use so much memory?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try FMDB. It's a neat wrapper around the sqlite c API.

http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/03/fmdb_for_iphone.html

Comment: Works, but you'd be better off using Core Data.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, because this was what I asked for in the question. However, I think I will be using Core Data instead.

Comment: @bbum Why do you think it would better to use Core Data? Could you please explain your opinion? Thanks!

Comment: Core Data has optimizations that are not possible in 3rd party code, takes advantage of numerous system APIs, and, though quite tricky, has iCloud synchronization support (yes, it has issues now, but they are being rapidly addressed).   There is nothing wrong with FMDB -- it is quite good -- but it is a relatively primitive tool by comparison.  Unless you truly need a raw relational persistence layer, Core Data is likely a better solution.   See @drharris's answer for more.

Answer (score 7):

[Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) is Apple's method to persist objects on the iPhone. This is also the most common method for storing data when developing for OS X and future Apple technologies, so it's worth spending the time to learn. The Apple Docs (linked above) are the best place to learn about this since they don't get outdated easily. Additional tutorials can be found through your favorite search engine.

In addition to making persistence very easy to do, it offers the following benefits:

- Only store objects in memory that you need, to save memory usage
- Migration and versioning support
- Graphical-based schema editor in Xcode
- Automatic support for undo/redo

Comment: Thank you :) I will be using this instead, as this is more supported by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [PLDatabase](http://code.google.com/p/pldatabase/).

> A SQL database access library for
>   Objective-C, initially focused on
>   SQLite as an application database. The
>   library supports both Mac OS X and
>   iPhone development.

Answer (score 2):

Google toolbox for Mac http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/ also includes a nice little sqlite wrapper, in `Foundation/GTMSQLite.h`. It isn't included in the provided iphone .xcodeproj but it does compile if you add it and its (minor) dependencies to an iphone project. Two classes: a db handle, and a prepared statement/resultset, with the expected methods on each.